# Parent and child process end randomly (linux, c, fork())

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipeline

The task wast to sort in an ascending order the array from the input.dat, using fork and divide and conquer algorithm.

So i wrote a code using this, but the parent process end faster than the child. I have the following line in my code but the parents will not wait for their children.

```
while(wait(NULL)>0);
```

A little explanation for my code:

In the input.dat is an array with the following form:

(long of the array) (space) (first number) (space) (second number) ...

example:

6 2 3 1 4 5 6

So I read in the array, and I split it to two arrays created in two structs, for writhing into the pipe. After that I call the divitimp function , a little explanation for the form:

(in my code)
divitimp(readwhilegoingdown(lefeleolvas),writewhilegoingdown(lefeleir),readwhilecomingup(felfeleolvas),writewhilecomingup(felfeleir))

After the divitimp function started I use fork, If it works(no errors) I look if it is the child or the parent process(the code is the same in the if and in the else), after that (in the if ) I read out one struct from the pipe if the array in the struct is not longer than two element I write the sorted struct to the writewhilecomingup pipe and not calling back the divitimp function, if the array is longer than 2, I split the array to two arrays created in two structs and i write them to writewhilegoingdown pipe and calling back the divitimp function.

After these I want to wait until the child process end and I use merge sort to sort the sorted arrays and then I write the results(eredmeny) in to the writewhilecomingup pipe.

After the divitimp function finished i go back to main and read the solution struct from the readwhilegoingup pipe, and write it to the output.dat.

The problem is the processes (parent and child) end in a random order.

Source code (very long sorry, but without the code I
 can't explain the problem):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct{
int n;
int a[100];
}TOMB;

void divitimp(int lefeleolvas, int lefeleir,int felfeleolvas,int felfeleir){
pid_t pid;
int i;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0){
    perror("fork hiba");
}
else{
    printf("pid= %i \n",pid);
    if(pid==0){
        TOMB valtozo;
        read(lefeleolvas,& valtozo, sizeof(valtozo));
        if(valtozo.n>2){
            TOMB sv,sv1;
            sv.n=valtozo.n/2;
            sv1.n=valtozo.n-valtozo.n/2;
            printf("Uj ismetles:%d ",sv.n);
            for(i=0;i<sv.n;i++){
                    sv.a[i]=valtozo.a[i];
                printf(" %d ",sv.a[i]);
            }
            int ai=sv1.n-1;
            printf(" *%d* ", sv1.n);
            for(i=0;i<sv1.n;i++){
                sv1.a[i]=valtozo.a[ai];
                ai++;
                printf(" %d ",sv1.a[i]);
            }
            printf("itt a vege\n");
            write(lefeleir,& sv,sizeof(sv));
            write(lefeleir,& sv1,sizeof(sv1));
            divitimp(lefeleolvas, lefeleir, felfeleolvas, felfeleir);
        }           
        else{
            if(valtozo.n==1){
                write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));
            }
            else{
                if(valtozo.n==2);{
                    if(valtozo.a[0]<valtozo.a[1]){
                        write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));
                    }
                    else{
                        int csere=valtozo.a[1];
                        valtozo.a[1]=valtozo.a[0];
                        valtozo.a[0]=csere;
                        write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
                    TOMB valtozo;
                    read(lefeleolvas,& valtozo, sizeof(valtozo));
                    if(valtozo.n>2){
                            TOMB sv,sv1;
                            sv.n=valtozo.n/2;
                            sv1.n=valtozo.n-valtozo.n/2;
                            printf("Uj ismetles:%d ",sv.n);
                            for(i=0;i<sv.n;i++){
                                    sv.a[i]=valtozo.a[i];
                                    printf(" %d ",sv.a[i]);
                            }
                            int ai=sv1.n-1;
            printf(" *%d* ", sv1.n);
                            for(i=0;i<sv1.n;i++){
                                    sv1.a[i]=valtozo.a[ai];
                                    ai++;
                                    printf(" %d ",sv1.a[i]);
                            }
                            printf("itt a vege\n");
                            write(lefeleir,& sv,sizeof(sv));
                            write(lefeleir,& sv1,sizeof(sv1));
                            divitimp(lefeleolvas, lefeleir, felfeleolvas, felfeleir);
            exit(0);
                    }
                    else{
                            if(valtozo.n==1){
                                    write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));
                                    exit(0);
                            }
                            else{
                                    if(valtozo.n==2);{
                                            if(valtozo.a[0]<valtozo.a[1]){
                                                    write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));
                                            exit(0);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                    int csere=valtozo.a[1];
                                                    valtozo.a[1]=valtozo.a[0];
                                                    valtozo.a[0]=csere;
                                                    write(felfeleir,& valtozo,sizeof(valtozo));
                                            exit(0);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
    }
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    if(pid==0){
        TOMB sv,sv1,eredmeny;
        read(felfeleolvas,& sv,sizeof(sv));
        read(felfeleolvas,& sv1,sizeof(sv));
        int svi=0,sv1i=0;
        eredmeny.n=sv.n+sv1.n;
        for(i=0;i<sv.n+sv1.n;i++){
            if(svi<sv.n&&sv1i<sv1.n){
                if(sv.a[svi]<sv1.a[sv1i]){
                    eredmeny.a[i]=sv.a[svi];
                    svi++;
                }
                else{
                    eredmeny.a[i]=sv1.a[sv1i];
                    sv1i++;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(svi<sv.n){
                    eredmeny.a[i]=sv.a[svi];
                svi++;  
                }
                else{
                    eredmeny.a[i]=sv1.a[sv1i];
                    sv1i++;
                }
            }
            printf("e=%d sv=%d sv1=%d\n",eredmeny.a[i],sv.a[svi-1],sv1.a[sv1i-1]);

        }
        write(felfeleir,& eredmeny, sizeof(eredmeny));

    }
   }
 }

int main(){
    FILE *f= fopen("input.dat","r");
if(!f){
perror("nincs megfelelo allomany");
exit(1);
}
    FILE *g= fopen("output.dat","w");
int n;
fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
int a[n];
a[0]=n;
int i=0;
printf("%d",n);
for(i;i<n;i++){
fscanf(f,"%d",&a[i]);
}
//printf("%d \n",n);
TOMB betesz1, betesz2;
    betesz1.n=n/2;
    for(i=0;i<betesz1.n;i++){
    betesz1.a[i]=a[i];
printf("%d\n ",a[i]);   
}
    betesz2.n=n-n/2;
    int ai=betesz2.n;
    for(i=0;i<betesz2.n;i++){
    betesz2.a[i]=a[ai];
    ai++;
printf("%d\n ",a[ai-1]);
}
    int pfd[2];
    if (pipe(pfd) < 0){
    perror("pipe hiba");
}
    int pfd1[2];
    if (pipe(pfd1) < 0){
    perror("pipe hiba");
}
    write(pfd[1],& betesz1, sizeof(betesz1));
    write(pfd[1],& betesz2, sizeof(betesz2));

divitimp(pfd[0],pfd[1],pfd1[0],pfd1[1]);
TOMB eredmeny;
read(pfd1[0],& eredmeny,sizeof(eredmeny));
printf("%d\n",eredmeny.n);
for(i=0;i<eredmeny.n;i++){
    fprintf(g,"%d ",eredmeny.a[i]);
}
fclose(f);
fclose(g);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to have to say this, but the code's indention/format/layout is an unreadable mess. Please be so kind to clean this up.

Comment: that's why I wrote explanation for the code

Comment: Fixing root causes is always the preferred option. So if you would be so kind ... - to do so you might like to have a look at the `indent` command, available from your Linux' shell.

Comment: Code that's ugly to look at, with inconsistent indentation among other formatting problems, is also *hard to understand*.  There's a reason why experienced developers take the time to cleanly format code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's hard to parse (aka read), which I'd put before "understanding" ...

Comment: @alk *It's hard to parse (aka read), which I'd put before "understanding" ...* Indeed. If you can't read it, you can't even get  start to understand it.  I've heard way too many inexperienced developers say something like, "It's my code and I'm the only one that needs to read and understand it."  They think they'll be able to read and understand the morass of different indentations, variable naming, and line lengths immediately the next morning, a week or two later, or even 6 months or several years later.  Guess what?  No you won't.  You'll be lucky to understand it even if it's perfect.

Comment: I have the solution, but thank you for telling these, next time I will be more cautious while writing the code to be more readable.

Comment: When calling system functions, like `fopen()`, always check (usually) the returned value for errors, then handle those errors.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via 1 blank line 2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent). 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  4) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: variable names (and function names) should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `a[]`, `n`, betesz#, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: regarding: `for(i;i<n;i++){`  the first parameter is not valid.  The first parameter is for 'initialization' however, `i` initializes nothing.  Perhaps the line: `int i=0;` and `for(i;i<n;i++){` should be combined into: `for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ){`   Note: appropriate horizontal spacing (like after `,` and after `;` and inside parens makes the code ever so much easier to read/understand and the compiler produces the same code either way

Comment: regarding: `if(valtozo.n==2);{`   I'm not sure what your trying to do here.  However, that semicolor `;` probably should not be there

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when asking the user for information, always prompt the user, so they know what is expected of them.  Then always validate the input from the user (I.E. never trust the user to do the right thing)

Comment: in the `main()` function, when the call to `pipe()` fails, it would be best to exit the program

Comment: when calling `read()` and/or `write()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful and to note how many bytes were written/read

Comment: when a call to `fork()` fails, probably should exit the program.

Comment: the parent process should NEVER exit while there are child process(s) still running.  However, the parent process calls `exit()` in three places with out waiting for any child process(s) to exit.

Comment: this line: `while(wait(NULL)>0);` is called after the closing brace for the parent process (so child process(s) also execute this line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you confused the parent and child processes. fork() returns 0 in the child process, but you have exit(0)s on the else branch, which basically means you terminate the parents.

Try switching your if statements to pid != 0.

Comment: @alk because he didn't use a debugging tool!